Understanding the output of Kernel Density Analysis
I want to create activity hotspot maps (heat maps) of bird pairs using the Kernel Density tool in ArcGIS Pro, but can not for the life of me make sense of the output values. I've read all the help files and other posts on this topic, but I haven't been able to make it make sense for my specific example.
For ease of understanding, I'll give a little bit of information on my data. I essentially followed birds around in their territory and recorded the GPS coordinates of the locations I observed them at. Since the GPS accuracy was +/- 3m, I only created a new GPS point if it was more than 3m away from the nearest point. If I recorded a bird at a previously marked location, I would note the observation at that already existing point. Since I often observed birds at the same location (e.g. around the nest), I have some GPS points with up to 9 observations. I slightly altered the coordinates of those points with multiple observations (between -1.5 & 1.5m) so they could be treated as individual points for the analysis.
I would now like to create heat maps that show the activity/observation hotspots of each pair within their territory (i.e. where the most observations have been made). I ran the Kernel Density tool from the Spatial Analyst Toolbox in ArcGIS with the following settings:
Input feature: My point layer of 68 observations 
Population field: None 
Output cell size: 0.1 
Area units: Square kilometers
This is my output:

From how I understand it, the raster values represent points per area unit, so in my case bird observations per km², and they depend on the scale and the chosen area units. However, these values just don't make any sense to me since they're so ridiculously high. I ran the same analysis with the area units set to square meters, since the area my points are in is quite small (the furthest points are only ~70m from each other). The values then range from 0.001 to 0.217, but would that mean that in the highest density areas there are 0.217 observations per m²? Some of the points are less than 1m apart, so this does not make sense to me.
I have a hard time interpreting these values and therefore don't know how to create an informative legend with quantitative values for when I need to present this analysis.

In the symbology tab you should be able to set a range of values for each class/color. Perhaps you can lower the amount of classes and relabel them with the range of observations for each class. This won't change the actual values but for the purpose of creating a legend it should represent what you want shown in the legend.
